# How does removing armv7s xCode 4.6 valid architecture project property affect App Store distribution of my iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, xcode4.6, armv7

I have a project that I created before iPhone 5 was released and I'm working on this project in xCode 4.6. By default xCode changes the build architecture of new projects to include the latest iPhone 5 instruction set.

One of the issues I faced is that **a static library that I'm using for the project is not compiled for armv7s** (new iPhone 5 and possibly new iPad). The workaround is to change the valid architectures property during my debugging of the project to exclude armv7s:

[image]

**I'm interested in the implications of excluding the armv7s as a valid architecture from the xCode project>build settings.** Will my app crash on new armv7s devices? Will it not be sold to armv7s devices from the app store?

Thank you for clarifications!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem with a static library. We built for armv7 only until an update to the library was released that was built for armv7s as well.

The only thing that not having armv7s will affect is that the app won't be optimized for any new logic that armv7s brings over armv7. The new arm processors should be backwards compatible with armv7 so future devices should work fine with a build for armv7.